# Bootstrap 3 navbar dropdown menu full height

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, drop-down-menu, navbar, dropdown

i have a classic Bootstrap 3 navbar with a dropdown menu (https://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/).

I would like the menu dropdown to have the screen height. it's possible ?

Comment: Please post the code that you tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just giving `height` attribute for this sample may help for this. In-line style css applied for `drop-down` item.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="height:100vh;">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
  <p>This example adds a dropdown menu for the "Page 1" button in the 


navigation bar.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this script to get the solution.

`$(document).on("shown.bs.dropdown", ".dropdown", function () {
        $(this).children(".dropdown-menu").css("height",screen.height);
    })`

It's possible to do in CSS?